# can only debug not deploy xamarin app with System.Data.SqlClient class used

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm working on an android app in Xamarin. It will debug in VS2013 community absolutely fine, deploying it to my phone on a usb tether. However I try and deploy a full .pk file set for a website download (I know the user would have to agree to installing 'untrusted apps') after I go through a standard deployment via VS2013, I try a 'dry' installation via download from a site, this doesn't work. It starts fine, and runs up until an sql-command is executed (namely logging in). Not sure how to resolve this one. Any help would be great.

Comment: did you checked the logcat to see what exception is thrown?

Comment: How does one do that. I'm a sessioned c# programmer but android is a bit of a new concept to me.

Comment: You need to open the "monitor" tool from the Android sdk, select the device and launch the application, you will see all the output on the log pane.

Comment: Will do that and report back.  Many thanks

Comment: So the plot thickens , this seems to be a bug with the Encoding via a dependency of mono . See link
https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=39237

Answer (score 0):

So after some research the answer is simply to turn on 'west' as an option in project properties.

If this fails however this is a bug, and due to be fixed in 4.3 ? (apparently)

more information: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/25/problem-inserting-data-in-sql-server-in-release-mode